# How to create a refresh token in plain php?

Tags: php, jwt, token, refresh

I've been searching the web for an example/explanation on how to generate a refresh token myself. Not using any services like Oauth etc. Just in plain php.
I found many info on how to use them, but not how to create one.

I create a JWT like this:

```
$secret = "secret";

$header = json_encode(['typ' => 'JWT', 'alg' => 'HS256']);

function createJWT($user_id){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();

    global $header;
    global $secret;
    $payload = ['user_id' => $user_id, 'iat'=> $timestamp, 'exp'=>$timestamp+10];
    $payload = json_encode( $payload );
    $base64UrlHeader = str_replace(['+','/','='], ['-','_',''], base64_encode($header));
    $base64UrlPayload = str_replace(['+','/','='], ['-','_',''], base64_encode($payload));
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, $secret);
    $base64UrlSignature = str_replace(['+','/','='], ['-','_',''], base64_encode($signature));
    $JWT =$base64UrlHeader . '.' . $base64UrlPayload . '.' . $base64UrlSignature;

    return $JWT;
}
```

And when looking at the jwt.io debugger it works fine.

But since I want to use a refresh token so I can "create" more access tokens after they've expired I can't find any information on how to create such one.

What i understand the access token is stored in local storage/cookie while the refresh token is store in a database.

How do I create a refresh token, what info does it contain? I guess it's not just a random string. And what does the schema a of the database/table storing the refresh token look like?

Comment: I'm interested in the same issue. Is there a good resource you found in order to achieve this? And also how does the validation/authentication of the refresh token works? All the resources I came across involves either frameworks or libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked into the docs of JWT and it seemed like you just have to create a uuid, guid wich is just a uniq valu/string that's nearly impossible to hack.

I tooked that uuid and stored it in local storage as "refresh-token".
And I also stored in in a DB with a table containing:
ID | user_id | refresh-token | expireDate
So whenever the JWT had expired I use the long-lasting refresh token and check if that refresh token was present in the db and if it was not expired.
Then I sent back a new JWT along with a new refresh token.

Comment: How about putting examples of what you came up with?

Comment: I'm not even sure you need an ID/user_id in your database if you use JWT. The user_id is probably already available in the access token. I'm not sure that's the good way of implementing it tho, I just started reading about the subject.

Comment: Do not store refresh-token in localStorage. Doing so is a huge security flaw. You're suppose to Store it in httpOnly cookie.

Comment: @MarceloFonseca do not forget for XSRF vulnerability, see explanation for example here [Angular Blog - Disadvantages of Cookies - XSRF](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/#disadvantagesofcookiesxsrf)